# Add database to compiled application

Tags: xcode, cocoa, compiler-construction, sqlite

I am using an sqlite3 database in my xcode/ios application and would like the database to be copied into the compiled application folder.
I've added the .db file to the project, but it doesn't get copied.
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually due to the fact I was wrongly opening the database. Path used was simply "database.db", when I had to prefix the NSBundle folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target settings for your SQL database.

Comment: Settings seemed to be correct, I however found the issue inbetween.